# check data isit inside my array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var array =[cars/, tv/, computer/];

// check this 2 data

var data_1 = "directory/cars/model_1";

var data_2 = "directory/cars";

console.log(data_1) // return true
console.log(data_2) // return failure
```

i need to check those 2 data with my array , how do i check those two data using my array ? in data_1 , do i have break down the text only to start check it ? anyway i can check the data_1 have those text inside my array without break it down? or it has to be like that ?

Comment: yeah , but it will be okie if you use JavaScript

Comment: Your question is unclear to me , You want to check your data_1 or data_2 is in array ?